# Handling exception for S3 bucket fetch with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am doing something like below to get all the files inside my s3 bucket.

```
 for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='uploads/{}/'.format(name)):  # to get data from subfolder dir
            if obj.key.endswith(('.xlsx', '.csv')):
                paths.append(obj.key)
```

I need to handle a case where either there is no files inside the folder or the folder(`uploads/{}/`) itself doesn't exist. How do I handle this.

Comment: len(paths) == 0

Comment: Yeah , I could use this .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
try:
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/',
                                     Prefix='uploads/{}/'.format(name)):  # to get data from subfolder dir
        if obj.key.endswith(('.xlsx', '.csv')):
            paths.append(obj.key)
except s3.meta.client.exceptions.NoSuchKey:
    print("no such key in bucket")
```

Comment: `bucket.objects.filter` deosn't throw any exception for me. It gives me `s3.Bucket.objectsCollection(s3.Bucket(name='uploads1'), s3.ObjectSummary)
` . Here I have put some random bucket name which doesn't exist